# my https C++ code doesn't work on some sites (binance)

Tags: c++, ssl, https, openssl, cryptocurrency

I made a https class in C++ using OpenSSL. It works on most sites/urls, but doesn't work with the following sites/urls:

- https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&startTime=0&limit=1
- https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo

I can open them using a browser/wget/postman, so they aren't bad link.
I'm also sure my request/headers are valid & correct.
I suspected SSL versions problems, but I tried all the versions in OpenSSL but no luck (SSLv3, TLS 1.1/1.2)

The server close my connection immediately, even before I send my headers.

This is an example of what my request looks like, and I don't think it's wrong.
Because I can't find anything wrong and the same code works with other sites/urls.

```
GET /api/v1/exchangeInfo HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Host: api.binance.com
User-Agent: evo
```

I have no idea what caused it. Anyone knows why?

Thanks!!

```
  SslSocket ssl;
  st = ssl.create();
  st = ssl.connect("api.binance.com:443");

  const char* req_header = "GET /api/v1/exchangeInfo HTTP/1.1\r\n"
      "Host: " "api.binance.com" "\r\n"
      "\r\n";
  st = ssl.send(req_header, strlen(req_header));

  while (true){
      char buff[ 1024 ] = {};
      size_t recv_size = 0;
      st = ssl.recv(recv_size, buff, sizeof(buff) - 1);
      if (!st) break;

      if (recv_size > 0)
          fwrite(buff, 1, recv_size, stdout);
  }
```

I did something like this to setup my ssl socket:

```
const SSL_METHOD *method = SSLv23_client_method(); 
_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
_ssl = SSL_new(_ctx);
SSL_set_fd(_ssl, _socket.fd());
_socket.connect(addr);
SSL_connect(_ssl);
printf("SSL_get_version2: %s\n", SSL_get_version(_ssl));
```

Comment: Why don't you just compare HTTP request headers from your request with the request headers from browser developer tools? And make your request use the same fields. If it doesn't work then you've made a mistake with OpenSSL somewhere.

Comment: And please post a minimal example code, it's not polite to ask questions from someone without providing a minimum of information.

Comment: I tried to send the exact request headers, but doesn't work

Comment: Record the communication with Wireshark. That will tell you if the SSL cipher negotiation and key exchange was successful. I'm almost sure that it wasn't. You will also find a reason why there.

Comment: I tried with wireshark, but since it's encrypted, how can I tell?

Comment: But the same code works with other sites/urls..

Comment: How do you know your version of OpenSSL supports the same cipher suites that the web site offers?

Comment: I print my ssl version using SSL_get_version, it shows TLSv1.2, and I used firefox to find out the site is also using TLSv1.2

Comment: I just tried to use wireshark to monitor my communication. I used this filter "ip.dst_host=="52.222.238.158"", first I tested with a browser, and it works and I saw something, but I saw "nothing" when I program connects, not even a TCP connection first.

Comment: oh, wait a minute, its ip is changing everytime I ping it, so hard to tell which records in wireshark to look for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site requires that the client is using the SNI extension. Without SNI extension you get this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.binance.com:443
...
140269619467928:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:772:
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
```

With SNI extension you get this:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect api.binance.com:443 -servername api.binance.com
...
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

To use SNI in your code use [SSL_set_tlsext_host_name](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_servername_type.html). See [this code in s_client.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2/apps/s_client.c#L1402) for how to use this function.

Comment: Oh yes yes, it works now!!! Thanks Steffen!!! I just know what SNI is now.

Comment: Nice.  How did you determine that was the problem?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I've seen similar problems often enough. Server requiring SNI is one of the more common problems and easy to check with the openssl commands I have in my answer. It is also reported by [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).